# Error with Deezer Javascript API: Valid token required?

Tags: javascript, deezer

My Deezer-app used to work fine with the Javascript API, but stopped working recently.

I get the following error:

```
{"error": "VALID_TOKEN_REQUIRED":true},"results":{}}
```

I can't find any information about this error and I have no idea how to debug it.

The url is [www.rapucationals.com](http://www.rapucationals.com)

Update: Please check out the code (www.rapucationals.com).
This is the call that fails: http://www.deezer.com/ajax/gw-light.php?api_version=1.0&api_token=a7cadc94893e55c9fd79da702354c86b&method=song.getListData&input=3&cid=0053621bf26d2cf98

Comment: Well, from the error's name, it looks like your authentication token has expired for some reason (or you're failing to pass it).

Comment: Can you please post the javascript API call your making that stopped to work ? Also do you call the DZ.login method ? If so what is the response for the login call ?

Comment: I'm not using the DZ.Login method, I'm simply initializing a player. The player doesn't initialize and the Deezer API keeps returning "Valid Token Required" over and over again.